# Passing list of objects to model with object property MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass a list of javascript objects to a class with an object type parameter like so:

```
[HttpPost, Route("Save")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Save (int id, List<BaseDynamicSaveModel> models)
    {
        var widgets = await DataContext.Widgets
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(e => e.IsActive)
            .ToListAsync();

        var Messages = new List<object>();
        if (models != null)
        {
            foreach (var model in models)
            {
                if (model.Model != null)
                {
                    var widget = widgets.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.Equals(model.WidgetName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                    var dynamicViewModel = (IDynamicViewModel)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Registration.Models.Dynamic." + model.WidgetName + "ViewModel"));
                    dynamicViewModel.ListOrder = widget.ListOrder.HasValue ? widget.ListOrder.Value : 0;
                    dynamicViewModel.ViewName = widget.Name;
                    dynamicViewModel.Title = widget.Title;
                    await dynamicViewModel.Save(API, model);

                    Messages.Add(new { Message = dynamicViewModel.Message, Success = dynamicViewModel.Success });
                }
            }
        }

        return Json(Messages);
    }
```

BaseDynamicSaveModel looks like this:

```
public class BaseDynamicSaveModel : IDynamicSaveModel
{
    public string WidgetName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DynamicModelProperty> Model { get; set; }
}
```

And DynamicModelProperty looks like this:

```
public class DynamicModelProperty
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that Value always shows as {object} when passing non-primitive types while I'm debugging and I can't seem to access any of the data.

I did try using a Dictionary here but it would have to be Dictionary< string, object> and object was always null so I just created my own class for key/value pairs.

Each module has a ViewModel that is inherited from a BaseViewModel class that looks like this:

```
public class BaseDynamicViewModel : IDynamicViewModel
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int ListOrder { get; set; }

    public string ViewIcon { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Load(API.APIProvider API, int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual Task Save(API.APIProvider API, BaseDynamicSaveModel model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected object CopyProperties(object destination, BaseDynamicSaveModel source)
    {
        var destinationModel = destination;
        var destinationProperties = destinationModel.GetType();
        foreach (var destinationProperty in destinationProperties.GetProperties())
        {
            if (destinationProperty.CanRead)
            {
                var value = source.Model.Where(e => e.Key.ToLower() == destinationProperty.Name.ToLower()).Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault();

                if (value != null)
                {
                    //Need to check if property is nullable and get underlying type
                    var targetType = destinationProperty.PropertyType.IsNullable() ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(destinationProperty.PropertyType) : destinationProperty.PropertyType;
                    var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);

                    destinationProperty.SetValue(destinationModel, convertedValue, null);
                }
            }
        }

        return destinationModel;
    }
}
```

And in particular the save method for the module that is having issues (the rest of the code in this method is unimportant and I really can't show much unfortunately):

```
public override async Task Save(API.APIProvider API, BaseDynamicSaveModel model)
    {
        //The module is not really named Module3, it has been renamed for obvious reasons
        var saveModel = new Module3SaveModel();
        saveModel = (Module3SaveModel)CopyProperties(saveModel, model);
    }
```

In the controller, if you notice **await dynamicViewModel.Save(API, model);** is where I'm calling each of the module's save methods, for clarification.

I have 2 modules that save just fine because I'm only passing a single model with primitive types and no nested objects. For the 3rd module I'm passing a List of objects and this is where it fails. When object is not a primitive type is shows as only {object} in the debugger with no data, I can't use my CopyProperties method to set SaveModel because it seems to not have any data.

**Question:** How do I go about getting a list of objects from an AJAX call to a generic class to unwrap later using reflection or at least how I am attempting doing so?

I am at a loss. I would very much like to just have List as the argument in the controller but it needs to be generic because other modules will be using it. This seems like such a simple problem but google hasn't been much help (or perhaps my google skills are lacking).

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested in what I did to resolve the issue I just created a separate controller like so:

```
[HttpPost, Route("Save")]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Save(int id, List<List<DynamicModelProperty>> models, string name)
        {

        }
```

Which took a list of modules that are arrays. In the javascript I just determine if the model passed to save is an array and pass it to this controller.